# agrupar datos repetidos con un campo diferente

Tags: sql-server, sql

La siguiente consulta me devuelve todos los valores que son distintos agrupándolos  por: razonSocial. Los valores de los 5 campos que sean iguales se muestra una sola vez. si en cualquiera de los 5 campos hay una sola difErencia entre los valores se mostrara nuevamente aunque el resto de los 4 campos los vales sean iguales.

```
SELECT T1.RFCSAT, T1.NumEmpleadoSAT, t1.NumSeguridadSocialSAT, t1.CURPSAT, Max(t1.RazonSocialSAT) as razonSocial
  FROM DBENC60 t1
  LEFT JOIN eEmployee t2
    ON t2.RFC = t1.RFCSAT
 WHERE t2.RFC IS NULL and t1.RazonSocialSAT like '%MARIA FERNANDA%' GROUP BY T1.RFCSAT, T1.NumEmpleadoSAT, t1.NumSeguridadSocialSAT, t1.CURPSAT, t1.RazonSocialSAT
order by  t1.RFCSAT ASC


RFC             No emple   segSocia      CURP                RAZON SOCIAL

ZUCB870411BK2   0111252    43907752920  ZUCB770441HNLXLR05  GALLARDO MARTINEZ MARIA FERNANDA 
ZUCB870411BK2   0111252    43907752920  ZUCB770441HNLXLR05  GALALRDO MARTINEZ MARIA FERNANDA
```

El detalle que tengo aquí es que el valor de los cuatro campos son iguales excepto la razón social, ya que en lugar de GALLARDO en el segundo resultado, aparece como GALALRDO y por lo tanto me lo muestra como un valor diferente aunque evidentemente es el mismo. Solo que la momento de teclear hubo. Les agradecería si pudieran ayudarme, gracias

NO SE PUEDE ELIMINAR LOS VALORES

Comment: No parece lógico, cargar a la fuente de datos, con esos problemas de interfaz de usuario. Es más lógico, que la interfaz de usuario, solo permita escribir esos datos en un solo punto. En el resto de pantallas, lo lógico es incluir selectores, para escoger al usuario que ya se ha introducido. Tipo un desplegable con los usuarios. Planteado de otra manera, ¿Cuando un registro es coincidente?. Cuando tiene el 99% de los caracteres coincidentes. Y si tiene el 98. Y si ha escrito GALARDO MASTINEZ. ¿Ese vale? Y si ha escrito GALARDO MASTINEZ MARA FERNANDA

Comment: Sql server dispone de las funciones SOUNDEX y DIFFERENCE para evaluar la semejanza de dos cadenas. https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/soundex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 y https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/difference-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Elimina `t1.RazonSocialSAT`  del  `GROUP BY`